# editing record on joined table from one of it's associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Recipe which has_many recipe_ingredients and has_many ingredients through recipe_ingredients. I am trying to edit a record on the recipe_ingredients table in the recipe controller. Right now with the form I have, it lists ALL the fields for editing(I just want one). The other thing is it's not updating the record at all.  Thank you in advance for any light you're able to shed on this problem. Here is the edit form.

```
<%= form_for @recipe, remote: true do |recipe_form| %>
  <%= recipe_form.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <%= f.number_field :amount, step: :any %>

    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and the controller.

```
def edit
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe_ingredients = @recipe.recipe_ingredient
  end

  def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.recipe_ingredients = RecipeIngredient.where(recipe_id: params[:id])
  end


  private

  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :recipe_ingredient_ids => [], :ingredient_ids => [])
  end
```

Comment: The problem with the records not updating is probably a result of your recipe_params method. To update a child record through a parent form, you need to specify which attributes of the child are permitted. If you can show your schema, I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

No the best way but I added `:recipe_ingredients` to routes and moved the edit and create to the `ingredients_controller` *and* added this super ugly path_helper, lol.

```
resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show ]
  resources :recipes, :recipe_ingredients do
    resources :ingredients, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  end



 <tbody>
      <% @recipe.recipe_ingredients.each do |recipe_ingredient| %>

      <tr>
        <td><%#= check_box_tag "recipe_ingredient_ids[]", recipe_ingredient.id %> </td>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.ing_name %></td>
        <td><%= recipe_ingredient.amount %> <%= link_to 'Edit Ingredient',
                  edit_recipe_ingredient_ingredient_path(recipe_ingredient) %> </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

And the updated update action

```
def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.find(params[:recipe_id])
    recipe_ingredient.update(amount: params[:recipe_ingredient][:recipe_ingredients][:amount].to_f)
    # require "pry"; binding.pry
    redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
  end
```

I'm sure there's a much better way to do this, I'm jsut so fried, lol.